# Is it possible to capture (intercept), alter, and resend a print stream in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find a way to capture or intercept the print stream (i.e. the resulting data when a user prints a web page) from a specific site and then give them some options to adjust it (via an extension popup) and alter the print data and then send it along to the printer. I don't see anything in the documentation that explains how to get in the middle of the printing process.

Alternatively, if there was a way to basically intercept the print processing completely and just take it over entirely I could work with that as well.

This may not be possible at all but if it is I could really use some pointers to docs or sample code or even a hint.

Comment: I guess this is not possible then

Comment: Old post but: I want to do this too!  There is a new API, but it only seems to let you create "fake" printers that only your extension can interact with: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider